# prevent docker from running multiple containers with same image

Tags: docker

I have a docker image which I create a container from, I want to make sure that after creating the first container no one will create another container with the same image.

Is there a docker command or flag to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such flag. It is in fact quite common to create many containers from the same image.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You could give your container a fixed name. Since the name must be unique on the host, it would make it impossible to start a second container on the same host.

Comment: Yeah but then someone can do docker run IMAGE_ID and it will create another container with that image. I think creating a wrapper script that accepts as a parameter the IMAGE_ID and checks if there's a running container with that image is also a plausible solution